# obj1 undefined in an algorithm for deep comparison

Tags: javascript

JS CODE:

```js
function deepEqual(obj1, obj2) {
  f = false; //comparison result
  if (Object.keys(obj1).join("") === Object.keys(obj2).join("")) { //checking if properties are equal
    var table = Object.keys(obj1);
    for (let entry of table) {
      console.log("entry",entry); //outputs value  
      console.log("obj1",obj1);
      console.log("obj1.entry",obj1.entry); // why is it undefined(if I write obj1.value it outputs 10)
      if (obj1.entry == obj2.entry) {
        f = true;
      } else {
        f = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return f;
}

console.log(deepEqual({value:10},{value:10}));
```

Comment: `obj1` is not undefined, it the `entry` key on the `obj1` which is undefined.

Comment: Fixed your snippet.

Comment: Please: `f = obj1.entry === obj2.entry`

Comment: this wont work, if key sequence is wrong.!

Answer (score 0):

Lot of issue with code, you can simplify it as below.

```js
function deepEqual(obj1 = null, obj2 = null) {
  if (obj1 === null || obj2 === null) return false;
  if (typeof obj1 !== "object") return obj1 == obj2;
  if (Object.keys(obj1).length !== Object.keys(obj2).length) return false;
  for (let key in obj1) {
    const result = deepEqual(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
    if (!result) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(
  deepEqual(
    { a: 10, value: 10, b: { c: 10 } },
    { b: { c: 10 }, value: 10, a: 10 }
  )
);

console.log(
  deepEqual(
    { a: 10, value: 10, b: { c: 10 } },
    { b: { c: 10, a: 1 }, value: 10, a: 10 }
  )
);
```